CannotVerifyCopySource error when using BlobBlobClient.StartCopyFromUri method
I was using the StartCopyFromUri method in BlobBlobClient to copy an image from an https source into blob storage and I keep getting this error.
Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Method Not Allowed
Status: 405 (Method Not Allowed)
ErrorCode: CannotVerifyCopySource
How do I fix the issue?
